# Can I recover my phone after system wiping in TWRP?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

Sorry for my English it is not so good.

I've done something stupid. I've wiped my system in TWRP mode.
So I've tried to reboot but it stucks on boot screen.          I think that my whole operating system is lost.
So I want to ask if there is a chance to recover my phone. Thanks in advance.

Phone model: HTC M7 running Android 4.4.4
Note : My phone can not connect to pc.

Comment: The chances to recover your phone would be great if you provide some informations regarding the device: the model,  android version

Comment: @esQmo thanks for reply.. it is an HTC One M7, Android 4.4.4

Comment: Well, You just need a RUU file for your phone model and htc drivers then boot in bootloader and flash the phone.

Comment: @esQmo OK but i dont know any thing about the RUU file

Comment: Is your bootloader unlocked?

Comment: Yes it is unlocked

Comment: You'll need to relock in order to flash a RUU file

Comment: Ok when i relock it where can I find the RUU file

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conditions for flashing RUU**

1. Bootloader LOCKED or RELOCKED when S-ON (*This condition can be ignored when S-OFF*)
2. RUU Software version must be **EQUAL** or **HIGHER** than  the device version (*This condition can be ignored when S-OFF*)
3. MID match of RUU and the device (*This condition can be ignored when S-OFF and SuperCID*)
4. CID match of RUU and device (*This condition can be ignored when S-OFF and SuperCID*)
5. HTC Sync Manager drivers installed (*You may install Sync Manager to obtain the drivers and then remove Sync Manager again, because its an extremely annoying, stupid software, that interferes with the RUU.exe and breaks the update process – the drivers install separately from the package and will stay when you remove Sync Manager – you only need those drivers*).

**Prerequisites**

- Download RUU form [here](http://www.htc.com/us/support/rom-downloads.html) or [here](http://androidruu.com/?developer=M7)
- Download HTC Sync Manager from [here](http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx)
- Boot in bootloader then connect the USB cable, you should see FASTBOOT **USB**
- Open a [terminal](https://androidmtk.com/download-minimal-adb-and-fastboot-tool) and tape `fastboot reboot RUU`, the device should reboot in RUU mode (Dark screen)
- Double click the RUU downloaded previously and wait the end of the process.

PS: First, relock the bootloader otherwise the flashing won't succeed: 
Boot in Fastboot mode then tape `fastboot oem lock`

Comment: Thanks a lot..dear but I've noticed that my phone cannot connect to my pc due of device descriptor issue..

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When i plug my phone in the pc it does not recognize it. In the device manager it says Device Descriptor Request Failed ...

Comment: Do you have drivers installed?

Comment: Yes I've downloaded and installed that but if you know where else I can get it

Comment: Download HTC Sync Manager, it will install proper drivers. And please check the USB cable or phone USB connector m